# What would be a good way to store categorized data on a database? (ex. Facebook albums)

Tags: database, database-design, relationship, categories

When dealing with data that has categories, such as videos + genres, and Albums + photos, what are ways to store those relationships in a database? For example, if I have a bunch of images (lets say A, B, C, D), and as a user I store it into a category called "My Family", how could those images be related to that one category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use "Many to Many" relationships or "Many to One" relationships.
Videos to Genres is Many to Many
Photos to Albums is Many to One OR Many to Many
Image to Category is Many to Many

Within a Python based Django application your schema might look like this...

```
from django.db import models

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    synopsis = models.TextField()
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    video_file = models.FileField(upload_to="movie_files_folder")
```

The Django API suppresses the details about the SQL schemas which will eventually be build using these models.  Also it suppresses how exactly these two models are associated.  In my experience those details are not necessary to making an database driven application function properly.

From what I understand, `Video.genres` is just a list of primary keys.  When you call `Video.genres.all()` it uses a list of primary keys such as `[5, 7, 9]` to find data stored in the `Genre` table

Comment: wouldn't videos to genres be many to one? If you have a video on technology, it's only going in technology. Or is that up for interpretation? Isn't it simple to just use Many-To-One in that case? P.S, I'm using Django also.

Comment: Yeah, I guess its up for interpretation.  It depends on how specific your genres are... Forrest Gump is a Drama.  Its also a "Coming of Age" Story.  The good thing about many to many is that you can have one or many, rather than just being limited to one.  Use many to many unless there is a specific reason to use many to one.